# Неверная работа скрипта (возможно из-за смены версии jQuery?)

Tags: jquery

Есть такой код (news ticker):

```
var first = 0;
var speed = 700;
var pause = 9000;

    function removeFirst(){
        first = $('ul#listticker li:first').html();
        $('ul#listticker li:first').animate({opacity: 0}, speed).hide('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
        addLast(first);
    }

    function addLast(first){
        last = '<li style="display:none">'+first+'</li>';
        $('ul#listticker').append(last);
        $('ul#listticker li:last').animate({opacity: 1}, speed).show('slow');   
    }

interval = setInterval(removeFirst, pause);
```

Скрипт должен убирать первую и добавлять в конце списка. Недавно случайно заметил что после нескольких циклов прокрутки (примерно минут через 3-5) в цикле появились дубли, т.е. повторяющиеся записи (до 10 копий). Скрипт установлен на сайте: http://www.dragons-lair.ru/ - раздел "новые книги". Подозреваю что ошибка появилась после обновления версии jQuery до 2.1.0, но не уверен в этом. Прощу помощи, заранее спасибо.

Comment: я правильно понимаю что вы просто перемещаете первый элемент в конец ?

если да, то возможно вам поможет знание, что если вы уже  существующий элемент в DOM добавите куда нибудь, то он исчезнет из предыдущего места: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/ZXSCF/

Comment: по сути там список из 20 элементов <li>. скрипт убирает первый элемент и добавляет к последнему, при этом сдвигает список вверх. Получается бесконечный цикл. Давно работало нормально, а вот сейчас есть косяки :( почему то добавляется в конец не один раз, а несколько раз.

Comment: http://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval#очередь-и-наложение-вызовов-в-setinterval

хммм, кажется проблема разрешилась после перемещения вызова функции: 

    $('ul#listticker li:first').animate({opacity: 0}, speed).hide('slow', function() {$(this).remove(); addLast(first);});

Comment: @Elven, зачем вам там remove.... вы посмотрите мой пример :)

Comment: Каюсь не посмотрел сразу скрипт, сейчас увидел. Да ваш вариант лучше :)